# Running .s file with yasm

Tags: android, assembly, terminal, cpu, binutils

I want start learning *Assembly*. But, there is a problem. I can't run my file.

I tried to use `yasm file.s -o run` and after `./run`, but I see this:
`bash: ./run: Permission denied`
After, I searched and found this:
Using this on terminal:
`~$ yasm -felf64 file.s`
`~$ ld file.o -o run`
`~$ ./run`.
But, I saw this error:
`ld: file.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format`
What should I do?
I'm running this on Android 11, with Termux 0.118.0 . CPU: Samsung Exynos Octa 7904.

Comment: You have an ARM cpu but try to use x86-64 code.

Comment: Different CPU architectures use different machine code.  YASM can only create x86(-64) machine code.  Samsung Exynos Octa 7904 has an AArch64 CPU.  So you'll need an x86-64 emulator to run ELF64 binaries.  (Also, assembly language is specific to the OS, e.g. the system-call ABI depends on the OS.  A tutorial telling you to use `yasm -felf64` is probably using Linux system calls, the same kernel that Android runs on, so you want something that emulates a Linux x86-64 environment, perhaps QEMU-user)

Comment: Thanks. But how can I run x86_64 on termux?

Comment: @Nico Yes, by running Termux on a PC.

Comment: @fuz thanks. What if .s files (or anything that Idk) can't run arm, how can i run arm?

Comment: @Nico ARM is a different architecture with a different assembly language and instruction set.  If you follow a tutorial for ARM (specifically AArch64), then your code should run on your phone.

Comment: `.s` "can run arm" but you need to put aarch64 code into it and not use `yasm` to assemble.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I will search about it.